# NotifyIcon in SytemTray. Setting width and height

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some code to show some text as the icon in the system tray:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);



        // Create a bitmap and draw text on it

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(16, 16);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        graphics.DrawString("sometext", DefaultFont, brush, 0, 0);



        // Convert the bitmap with text to an Icon
        IntPtr hIcon = bitmap.GetHicon();
        Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(hIcon);
        notifyIcon1.Icon = icon;
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormWindowState.Minimized == WindowState)
        {
            Hide();
        }
    }

    private void notifyIcon1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Show();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
```

But the icon is always a square and because of this, not all the text is displayed.

Is there a way to create an wider icon?

Comment: I don't think there is... but at the same time, the icon isn't the place to really display text, thats what the notification should be doing

Comment: Yes, i understand. I just want to display a security code so it can be read without clicking ore something else...
Maybe i have to create a notification icon for each character :-)

Comment: If you started doing that I'd start disabling notifcations from your application ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN:Notifications and the Notification Area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee330740(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Notification area icons should be high-DPI aware. An application
>   should provide both a 16x16 pixel icon and a 32x32 icon in its
>   resource file, and then use LoadIconMetric to ensure that the correct
>   icon is loaded and scaled appropriately.

So you cannot create wide icon. And as @Sayse said, the icon is not a place to display text.