# Custom width notify icon

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

I am trying to customize a notify icon. I don't want an image on the icon, but I want text. I can already do this through this thread:
[Writing text to the system tray instead of an icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379547/writing-text-to-the-system-tray-instead-of-an-icon)[Writing text to the system tray instead of an icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379547/writing-text-to-the-system-tray-instead-of-an-icon)

The problem I have is I want to show a text of at least 5 characters and with an eligible size it no longer fits and only shows two or three characters.
Is there any way to make the icon wider? There are icons such as the keyboard preferences and the one that shows the date and time are larger than what you can configure with notify icon.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: An application should provide both a 16x16 pixel icon and a 32x32 icon in its resource file. The icon is not a place to display text. See [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/notification-area?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use tray icons then? They [have limits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32266491/1997232) and your requirement doesn't seems to fit. There should be a way to customize windows taskbar panel (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions)), not sure if customizing tray area possible at all.

Comment: *"There are icons such as the keyboard preferences and the one that shows the date and time"* - those two are probably just right aligned taskbar extensions, they doesn't looks like a part of tray to me.

Comment: @ɐsɹǝʌǝɔıʌ You are right but for trying.

Comment: @Sinatr It may be, I am not sure.

Comment: @Garmael I'm almost sure you cannot create a wide icon for the system tray.